# C# LDAP AD Authentication, use Job Title for authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, ldap, userprincipal

I have seen many online articles and sample codes on how to use Role-based authorization, but can't find anything related to title-based authorization.

I have the following in a class for AD Authentication:

```
 protected ClaimsIdentity CreateIdentity(UserPrincipalExtended userPrincipal)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(MyAuthentication.ApplicationCookie, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType,
            ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(
            "http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider",
            "Active Directory"));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userPrincipal.Name));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, userPrincipal.GivenName ?? string.Empty));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, userPrincipal.Surname ?? string.Empty));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(userPrincipal.Title, userPrincipal.Title ?? string.Empty));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(userPrincipal.Department, userPrincipal.Department ?? string.Empty));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userPrincipal.SamAccountName));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userPrincipal.EmailAddress))
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, userPrincipal.EmailAddress));

        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        var dirEntry = (DirectoryEntry) userPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject();
        foreach (string groupDN in dirEntry.Properties["memberOf"])
        {
            var parts = groupDN.Replace("CN=", "").Split(',');
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, parts[0]));
        }


        if (claims.Count > 0)
            identity.AddClaims(claims);


        var title = dirEntry.Properties["title"].Value.ToString();
        return identity;
    }
```

This works fine, and I can see the correct title and department retrieved from the Active Directory. Obviously I am using an extended UserPrincipal, since the title and department are not part of the standard UserPrincipal.

My problem is that I can't get the title and department values passed to my Controller for Authorization.

In HomeController, I get the information of the authenticated user by using the following:

```
var firstname = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.GetFirstname();
var lastname = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.GetLastname();
var email = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.GetEmail();
var uid = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.GetUserID();
```

Obviously this uses the standard IPrincipal which does not contain provisions for title and department.

Is there a simple way to pass the title and department parameters to the controller? and is it possible to use the title for Authorizing access rather than Roles?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't recall `IPrincipal` have those methods, I assume those are your own extension to `IPrincipal`, so I don't see why you can't do the same for Title and Department. To authorize by Title and Department, you can create your own Authorize filter attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar challenge and solved it by using the (here in your case) titles and departments as roles.
This allows to use all out-of-the-box role based authorization features.

```
if (userPrinciple.Title != null)
{
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userPrincipal.Title));
}

if (userPrincipal.Department != null)
{
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userPrincipal.Department));
}
```

If the roles are department specific, you can combine both.

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, $"{userPrincipal.Department}.{userPrincipal.Title}));
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. I am not sure if this would work, as I have already added the Claims in the Model, and the correct title and department are obtained from the Active Directory. My problem is passing these values to the HomeController.

Comment: Your code adds them as 'nformational' claims, not as something that can be used for authorisation  (read:roles). The code in the answer creates roles; this allows the AuthorizeAttributes to do their work. So actually there is no need to access these from within the controller, moreover you don't want the controller method concerned to be executed when the AuthorizeAttribute applied on it can't be fullfilled.

Comment: Brilliant! This worked like a charm. Thank you so much.
Now is there any way I can use the Title or Department for conditional statements in the View?
Something like if the title equals x then display the Admin navigation tab; otherwise hide it.

Comment: Also for this, think in roles; via the user (which is an IPrincipal) you can check its role (here: the title and/or department) via the IsInRole method of this IPrincipal.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a million.

Comment: All working great so far, but I can't find a way to display the Title and Department in a ViewBag message.